# How to find untracked files in a Perforce tree? (analogue of svn status)

Tags: version-control, language-agnostic, perforce

Anybody have a script or alias to find untracked (really: unadded) files in a Perforce tree?

EDIT: I updated the accepted answer on this one since it looks like P4V added support for this in the January 2009 release.

Comment: I cannot imagine how it come that the most used corporate SCM tool is missing this functionality. Probably all their developers are using only the GUI.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud!!!!    The accepted `p4 status` doesn't just FIND untracked files, it actually STARTS TRACKING THEM.   I.e. `p4 status` is not a read-only query, as one would suspect from the name, but is actually a command that changes stuff - not the workspace files.   This is NOT what a status command should do, and NOT what `svn status` does.   The closest thing I can find to `svn status` is `p4 reconcile -na` - -a to say "files that should be added", -n to say "don't actually change anything".   /// I originally said something much stronger.

Comment: I revived http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642531/what-is-the-p4-command-equivalent-to-something-like-svn-status, which was incorrectly marked as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272/how-to-find-untracked-files-in-a-perforce-tree-analogue-of-svn-status, as new question [(What is the p4 command equivalent to something like git/hg/bzr/svn status? (Hint: not `p4 status`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937962/what-is-the-p4-command-equivalent-to-something-like-git-hg-bzr-svn-status-hint), and answered it myself. Better welcomed

Comment: Both `p4 reconcile` and `p4 status` are slow as hell, while `git status` finished executing in 1-3 seconds.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**EDIT:** Please use `p4 status` now. There is no need for jumping through hoops anymore. See @ColonelPanic's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13864328/39648).

In the Jan 2009 version of P4V, you can right-click on any folder in your workspace tree and click "reconcile offline work..."

This will do a little processing then bring up a split-tree view of files that are not checked out but have differences from the depot version, or not checked in at all.  There may even be a few other categories it brings up.

You can right-click on files in this view and check them out, add them, or even revert them.

It's a very handy tool that's saved my ass a few times.

EDIT: ah the question asked about scripts specifically, but I'll leave this answer here just in case.

Comment: Added a powershell solution in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217152/in-perforce-how-can-i-delete-files-from-a-directory-in-my-workspace-where-the-fil/3219246#3219246

Comment: Does this diff every single file against the version in the repo?  I've got a large repo and a slow connection (when working from home).  This could take forever!

Comment: I don't think it's a full diff, but it's not quick.

Comment: Worth mentioning that I ran this command on a 150MB directory with 7,300 files and 315 folders. It took less than 10 seconds to open the window. I also ran it on a different directory (1.1GB, 18,138 files, 1,404 folders) and it took about 50 seconds to open the window. Subsequent requests run in 5-10 seconds for both folders I tested. So I wouldn't be TOO afraid of this option being too slow (although, I'm not sure how dependent this is on my system specs). P4V 2013 March 20 on Windows 7.

Comment: Both `p4 status` and the p4v reconcile work great - but I thought I'd note that I especially liked the [error message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HqMCv.png) I got from p4v ...

Comment: Oh for crying out loud!!!!    `p4 status` doesn't just FIND untracked files, it actually STARTS TRACKING THEM.   I.e. `p4 status` is not a read-only query, as one would suspect from the name, but is actually a command that changes stuff - not the workspace files.   This is NOT what a status command should do, and NOT what `svn status` does.   The closest thing I can find to `svn status` is `p4 reconcile -na` - -a to say "files that should be added", -n to say "don't actually change anything".   /// I originally said something much stronger.

Comment: `p4 status` is basically a synonym for `p4 reconcile -n`.  Perhaps you ran `p4 status -A` which is a synonym for `p4 reconcile`?

Answer (score 50):

On linux, or if you have gnu-tools installed on windows:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 p4 fstat >/dev/null
```

This will show an error message for every unaccounted file.  If you want to capture that output:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 p4 fstat >/dev/null 2>mylogfile
```

Comment: Redirecting stderr to stdout will allow you to perform additional filtering or other operations.  For example, to see a scrollable list of Java files: find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 p4 fstat 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep '\.java ' | less

Comment: This takes insanely long on my 60K-files workspace. I have written a python script which does the same job in under 10 seconds: [p5](https://github.com/hamstergene/p5). It also supports `.p4ignore` and can preview and automatically edit untracked/changed/deleted files.

Comment: @hamstergene, very nice!

Comment: Wrote a [small script](https://github.com/arnonzilca/p4u/blob/master/p4-untracked) that does exactly that if anyone is interested (including dir argument, max depth argument & output to stdout).

Comment: Thanks; I found this useful! Note that this doesn't handle symlinks (`find . -type l`), and gives misleading output for P4 files forcibly added because they contain the `@` or `%` characters. However, such files are in the minority, so a manual review of these edge cases will work in most cases.

Comment: @hamstergene Perhaps something has changed, because I've got 400,000+ files in my workspace, and the command completed in < 20sec. However except for ~40 error messages (usually due to files containing `@`), all files in the directory had a corresponding file in Perforce. (I'm using P4/LINUX26X86_64/2014.2/978861)

Answer (score 19):

Under Unix:

```
find -type f ! -name '*~' -print0| xargs -0 p4 fstat 2>&1|awk '/no such file/{print $1}'
```

This will print out a list of files that are not added in your client or the Perforce depot. I've used `! -name '*~'` to exclude files ending with ~.

Answer (score 12):

Ahh, one of the Perforce classics :) Yes, it really sucks that there is STILL no easy way for this built into the default commands.

The easiest way is to run a command to find all files under your clients root, and then attempt to add them to the depot. You'll end up with a changelist of all new files and existing files are ignored.

E.g dir /s /b /A-D | p4 -x - add

(use 'find . -type f -print' from a nix command line).

If you want a physical list (in the console or file) then you can pipe on the results of a diff (or add if you also want them in a changelist).

If you're running this within P4Win you can use $r to substitute the client root of the current workspace.

Answer (score 12):

> Is there an analogue of `svn status` or `git status`?

**Yes, BUT**.

As of Perforce version 2012.1, there's the command `p4 status` and in P4V 'reconcile offline work'. However, they're both very slow. To exclude irrelevant files you'll need to write a `p4ignore.txt` file per     https://stackoverflow.com/a/13126496/284795

Comment: There have been several performance improvements to `p4 status` since the 2012.1 release. If you have been staying away from `p4 status` due to performance concerns, it might be worth testing it again to see how it behaves now.

Answer (score 6):

**2021-07-16: THIS ANSWER MAY BE OBSOLETE.**

I am reasonably sure that it was accurate  in 2016, for whatever version of Perforce I was using them (which was not necessarily the most current).  But it seems that this problem or design limitation has been remedied in subsequent releases of Perforce.  I do not know what the stack overflow etiquette for this is -- should this answer be removed?

**2016 ANSWER**

I feel impelled to add an answer, since the accepted answer, and some of the others, have what I think is a significant problem: they do not understand the difference between a read-only query command, and a command that makes changes.

I don't expect any credit for this answer, but I hope that it will help others avoid wasting time and making mistakes by following the accepted but IMHO incorrect answer.

**---+  BRIEF**

Probably the most convenient way to find all untracked files in a perforce workspace is `p4 reconcile -na`.

`-a` says "give me files that are not in the repository, i.e. that should be added".

`-n` says "make no changes" - i.e. a dry-run. (Although the messages may say "opened for add", mentally you must interpret that as "would be opened for add if not -n")

Probably the most convenient way to find all local changes made while offline - not just files that might need to be added, but also files that might need to be deleted, or which have been changed without being opened for editing via `p4 edit`, is `p4 reconcile -n`.

Several answers provided scripts, often involving `p4 fstat`.  While I have not verified all of those scripts, I often use similar scripts to make up for the deficiencies of perforce commands such as `p4 reconcile -n` - e.g. often I find that I want local paths rather than Perforce depot paths or workspace paths.

**---+ WARNING**

`p4 status` is NOT the counterpart to the status commands on other version control systems.

`p4 status` is NOT a read-only query. `p4 status` actually finds the same sort of changes that `p4 reconcile` does, and adds them to the repository. `p4 status` does not seem to have a `-n` dry-run option like `p4 reconcile` does.

If you do `p4 status`, look at the files and think "Oh, I don't need those", then you will have to `p4 revert` them if you want to continue editing in the same workspace.  Or else the changes that `p4 status` added to your changeset will be checked in the next time.

There seems to be little or no reason to use `p4 status` rather than `p4 reconcile -n`, except for some details of local workspace vs depot pathname.

I can only imagine that whoever chose 'status' for a non-read-only command had limited command of the English language and other version control tools.

**---+ `P4V` GUI**

In the GUI `p4v`, the reconcile command finds local changes that may need to be added, deleted, or opened for editing. Fortunately it does not add them to a changelist by default; but you still may want to be careful to close the reconcile window after inspecting it, if you don't want to commit the changes.

Comment: p4 status doesn't seem to add files. it appears to work like and is documented as 'reconcile -n'. are you sure it changes things?

Comment: @Krazy Glew you might want to check your client environment to make sure that someone isn't gaslighting you by aliasing `p4 status` to `p4 reconcile` or maybe `p4 status -A`.  I can assure you that `p4 status` does not open files by default.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively from P4Win, use the ""Local Files not in Depot" option on the left hand view panel.

I don't use P4V much, but I think the equivalent is to select "Hide Local Workspace Files" in the filter dropdown of the Workspace view tab.p4 help fstat

In P4V 2015.1 you'll find these options under the filter button like this:
[image]

Comment: This only shows files under the current directory, sadly :(

Answer (score 4):

I use the following in my tool that backs up any files in the workspace that differ from the repository (for Windows).  It handles some odd cases that Perforce doesn't like much, like embedded blanks, stars, percents, and hashmarks:

```
dir /S /B /A-D | sed -e "s/%/%25/g" -e "s/@/%40/g" -e "s/#/%23/g" -e "s/\*/%2A/g" | p4 -x- have 1>NUL:
```

"**dir /S /B /A-D**" lists all files at or below this folder (**/S**) in "bare" format (**/B**) excluding directories (/**A-D**).  The "**sed**" changes dangerous characters to their "**%xx**" form (a la HTML), and the "**p4 have**" command checks this list ("**-x-**") against the server discarding anything about files it actually locates in the repository ("**1>NUL:**").  The result is a bunch of lines like:

```
Z:\No_Backup\Workspaces\full\depot\Projects\Archerfish\Portal\Main\admin\html\images\nav\navxx_background.gif - file(s) not on client.
```

Et voilà!

Comment: This is a great solution, and still works with P4 version 2015.1

Comment: very fast! find/xargs runs out of memory and slow. Recall to double %'s when adding to .bat file.

Answer (score 2):

Quick 'n Dirty: In p4v right-click on the folder in question and add all files underneath it to a new changelist.  The changelist will now contain all files which are not currently part of the depot.

Answer (score 1):

The following commands produce status-like output, but none is quite equivalent to `svn status` or `git status`, providing a one-line summary of the status of each file:

- `p4 status`
- `p4 opened`
- `p4 diff -ds`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment, but Ross' solution also lists files that are open for add. You probably do **not** want to use his answer to clean your workspace.

The following uses `p4 fstat` (thanks Mark Harrison) instead of `p4 have`, and lists the files that aren't in the depot **and** aren't open for add.

```
dir /S /B /A-D | sed -e "s/%/%25/g" -e "s/@/%40/g" -e "s/#/%23/g" -e "s/\*/%2A/g" | p4 -x- fstat 2>&1 | sed -n -e "s/ - no such file[(]s[)]\.$//gp"
```

===Jac

Answer (score 0):

Fast method, but little orthodox. If the codebase doesn't add new files / change view too often, you could create a local 'git' repository out of your checkout. From a clean perforce sync, git init, add and commit all files locally. Git status is fast and will show files not previously committed.

Answer (score 0):

The `p4 fstat` command lets you test if a file exists in the workspace, combine with `find` to locate files to check as in the following Perl example:

```
// throw the output of p4 fstat to a 'output file'
// find:
//  -type f  :-  only look at files,
//  -print0  :-  terminate strings with \0s to support filenames with spaces
// xargs:
//  Groups its input into command lines,
//  -0       :-  read input strings terminated with \0s
// p4:
//  fstat    :-  fetch workspace stat on files

my $status=system "(find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 p4 fstat > /dev/null) >& $outputFile";

// read output file
open F1, $outputFile or die "$!\n";

// iterate over all the lines in F1
while (<F1>) {
  // remove trailing whitespace
  chomp $_;

  // grep lines which has 'no such file' or 'not in client'
  if($_ =~ m/no such file/ || $_ =~ m/not in client/){

     // Remove the content after '-'
     $_=~ s/-\s.*//g;

     // below line is optional. Check ur output file for more clarity.
     $_=~ s/^.\///g;

     print "$_\n";
  }
}

close F1;
```

Or you can use `p4 reconcile -n -m ...`

If it is 'opened for delete' then it has been removed from the workspace. Note that the above command is running in preview mode (`-n`).

Comment: Please do not just throw some code without any explanation as answer but add some explanation to help the OP understanding the code and learn something. :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed something that would work in either Linux, Mac or Windows. So I wrote a Python script for it. The basic idea is to iterate through files and execute `p4 fstat` on each. (of course ignoring dependencies and tmp folders)

You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/givanse/8c69f55f8243733702cf7bcb0e9290a9

Answer (score 0):

This command can give you a list of files that needs to be added, edited or removed:
p4 status -aed ...
you can use them separately too
p4 status -a ...
p4 status -e ...
p4 status -d ...

Answer (score -1):

In P4V, under the "View" menu item choose "Files in Folder" which brings up a new tab in the right pane.
To the far right of the tabs there is a little icon that brings up a window called "Files in Folder" with 2 icons. 
Select the left icon that looks like a funnel and you will see several options. Choose "Show items not in Depot" and all the files in the folder will show up.
Then just right-click on the file you want to add and choose "Mark for Add...". You can verify it is there in the "Pending" tab.
Just submit as normal (Ctrl+S).