# Ignore client generated files in Perforce workspace view

Tags: version-control, perforce, ignore

Is there a way to have Perforce ignore new files in a client workspace in the workspace view?

I have 120 java files that generate over 700 class files, so managing these files in a single folder view is tedious.  I recognize generating the output in a separate folder is an elegant solution but not one that is feasible at the moment.

[Question 55449](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449/can-you-ignore-a-file-in-perforce) relates to ignoring files that exist on the server, but the workspace view still includes these files.

EDIT: I'm trying to exclude just .class files (or some other arbitrary filter) not ALL files.  Reconcile Offline Work still shows these class files as well.

Comment: Why can't you just use the Depot view instead of the Workspace view?

Comment: That’s what I thought at first too, but then there may be times that BrianH will want to add a file that is located in such a way that these other files would have to be displayed by Perforce. But that would defeat the purpose of his question ... :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 -//folderName/folderName/folderName/*.class //workspaceName/folderName/folderName/*.class
```

If this line is in the "View" area of the Workspace, the "Reconcile Offline Work" will group all the .class files in an "Excluded Files" branch.  The class files will still show up in the workspace view however.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to remember to put BrianH's exclusion line in all your workspaces (aka client specs), then ask your administrator to filer out .class files in the P4 server permissions table. This will make it transparent to all users.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using P4V, select “Hide Local Files” from the “Filter Workspace” menu that is found in the “View” menu.

This works the same for the Windows and Macintosh clients.

Comment: You are correct with your comment above, I'm looking to just exclude specific files.  If I can ignore .class files, I can not worry about missing new files that I do care about.

Comment: @Lyndsey Ferguson: do you know how to do that in Folder Diff view?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using or can use the Eclipse Perforce plugin, then [the plugin documentation](http://perforce.com/perforce/doc.091/manuals/p4wsad/topics/adding.html) lists several ways to ignore files & folders.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the perforce executable you are using.

If you are using p4v.exe, you will find above the workspace view a yellow filter icon.  Selecting this icon will reveal a context menu.  One of the options is 'Hide Files Not in Depot.'  Selecting this should produce the desired results.

Comment: The problem with this is it hides ALL the files.  I'm looking to exclude specific (generated) files.

Comment: Unfortunately, although I see there is a way to filter your depot view by excluding/including files by extension and other options, I dont see any way to do this for local files.  In a perfect world, separating your source from your output would be an option.  Good luck with this one.