# Prevent Perforce from checking in unwanted files

Tags: perforce

In a project we are working on I would like to prevent several files from being checked in to our perforce depo. The files are either dll outputs from the build process  or computer specific config files. Someone checked in the app dlls in before I got here, it make me sad and now prevents me from building when I to a "get all".

I am new to perforce so if I am missing something really dumb please be kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke too soon. You can find answers at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449/can-you-ignore-a-file-in-perforce) SO question.