# Can you "ignore" a directory in P4V?

Tags: perforce

We use Visual Studio, which generates lots of `bin` and `obj` directories. When I use **P4V**'s "Reconcile Offline Work" feature, these appear in the "Local files not in depot" list.

I'd like to exclude them. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449/can-you-ignore-a-file-in-perforce), but that talks about files, and when I try what it suggests (adding the following to my workspace view), **it doesn't work**:

```
//depot/Foo/... //Client/Foo/...
-//depot/Foo/.../*.user //Client/Foo/.../*.user
-//depot/Foo/.../bin/... //Client/Foo/.../bin/...
-//depot/Foo/.../obj/... //Client/Foo/.../obj/...
```

It doesn't actually seem to work for files, either: the foo.csproj.user files are still displayed in the list.

Can I exclude directories from P4V? If so, how? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated answer**:
This has been somewhat tricky in the past, because there was no built-in way to exclude a directory from a Perforce command. Since 2012 this has changed.
You can have a look at [a nice perforce article for this problem](https://community.perforce.com/s/article/3451).

As of 2012.1, the `P4IGNORE` environment variable can be set to designate a file to be used to exclude files from Perforce.  Both the Perforce Server (p4d) and client (p4, P4V) need to be 2012.1 or greater.  `P4IGNORE`'s purpose is to ignore files when adding new files to the depot and reconciling workspaces.  Like comparable features in other version control systems, P4IGNORE cannot be used to ignore files already under the repository's control.

P4Eclipse manages `.p4ignore` files on its own terms.
(see the manual regarding this point [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4eclipse/topics/adding.html))

**Using client views to exclude files and directories:**

The traditional method for excluding files and directories in Perforce is to use exclusionary client mappings. See the command reference for Views for full documentation.  Example view:

*View:*

```
//depot/... //test_ws/depot/...
-//depot/dir/etc/... //test_ws/depot/dir/etc/...
```

This view will prevent files in dir/etc from being added to the depot. If trying to exclude the directory from read-only queries, use client or relative syntax.

```
$ p4 files //depot/dir/etc/...
//depot/dir/etc/foo#1 - add change 1186 (text)
//depot/dir/etc/bar#1 - add change 1186 (text) 


$ p4 files //test_ws/dir/etc/...
//test_ws/test_ignore/ignoredir/... - file(s) not in client view. 

$ cd dir/etc
$ p4 files ...
... - file(s) not in client view.
```

Alternatively, you can use shell commands to filter your output as desired.

```
p4 files //depot/dir/... |
    awk -F# '{print $1}' |
    grep -v "//depot/dir/etc/" |
    p4 -x - fstat
```

which runs p4 fstat on all files under "`//depot/dir/`", except for those files under "`//depot/dir/etc/`". This directory exclusion is accomplished by listing all of the files, and then using grep to remove those files under the directory to be excluded. The trailing slash in "`//depot/dir/etc/`" is necessary to prevent matching directories under "`//depot/dir/`" that start with "etc" (for example, "`//depot/dir/etc2009`").

**Note:**

The awk command assumes there are no file names containing the "#" character.
The grep command can also read its patterns from a file, which is useful if you need to exclude multiple directories.
We use the '-x -' flags with the p4 command to use the input as arguments to the corresponding command; see the Perforce Command Line Global Options for more information.

Comment: Gah. That's hideous, but might be the best way to do what I want. I'll give it a whirl later.

Comment: Why do companies pay money for this ?

Comment: This answer is no longer correct.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3103898/4228).

Comment: answer is updated to the actual state of perforce functionality

Comment: nice copy-paste from the p4 website

Answer (score 77):

As of version 2012.1, Perforce supports the `P4IGNORE` environment variable.  This allows you to specify files and directories to ignore when using the commands that search for or add new files (`p4 add`, `p4 status`, and `p4 reconcile`).

To use an ignore file, create a file in the root of your workspace and give it some meaningful name.  The convention seems to be something like *.ignore* or *.p4ignore*, but anything will do (I used *p4ignore.txt* so that I can edit it with a simple double-click).  Then fill it with your ignore rules.  The following will ignore the the unwanted debris generated by Visual Studio:

```
# directories
bin
obj

# files
*.suo
*.user
```

After you have created this file, set the `P4IGNORE` environment variable to point to it.  At the command line, type something along the lines of this:

```
p4 set P4IGNORE=C:\somepath\p4ignore.txt
```

**Be sure to use an absolute path!**  The [Perforce documentation](http://www.perforce.com/blog/120214/new-20121-p4ignore) doesn't specify this and my first attempt did not work (on Windows anyway) because I didn't specify an absolute path.

After doing this, any attempt to add files or directories that are in the ignore list will be rejected and you'll see a warning such as this (which they do give you the option to suppress):

[image: P4V 'ignored' files message]

---

If you are using a version of the Perforce server previous to 2012.1, you can still do this in your client spec.  The syntax of your exclusion rules is just a little off.  What you want is this:

```
-//depot/Foo.../*.user //Client/Foo.../*.user
-//depot/Foo...bin/... //Client/Foo...bin/...
-//depot/Foo...obj/... //Client/Foo...obj/...
```

Note the missing slashes after "Foo" and before "bin" and "obj".

Comment: That doesn't work for directories; I'm still seeing (e.g.) path\to\bin\Debug\Foo.pdb.
It does work for the foo.csproj.user files, though (which it didn't seem to be yesterday) Odd.

Comment: But it does seem to work in the Advanced Reconcile box. What's going on here?

Comment: Works for me using P4V 2010.2

Comment: This still requires all developers setting a P4IGNORE envar. Is there not a default ignore file that clients will honour? (Much like git's .gitignore file)

Comment: You can use the Ignored field in a stream, but it doesn't support embedded wildcards, and doesn't you let you ignore everything in a folder and then un-ignore specific files -- you need to be explicit about what is ignored.

Comment: You can use `p4ignore.txt` to ignore files and folders by name, but frustratingly wildcard rules are only applied to files. Buggy software :(

Comment: Do not set `P4IGNORE` to an absolute path. Set it to a *file name*. For example, `p4 set P4IGNORE=.gitignore`. Then you can put files of this name in any relevant directories and subdirectories, and Perforce will recognize them, similarly to git and `.gitignore`.

Comment: @ChuckBatson, the fact that an environment variable has to be set which points to a single file configuring the *entire* workspace still makes it far more cumbersome than creating a `.gitignore`.

Comment: @Hans What I'm saying is that when you don't use an absolute path, Perforce appears to look in each directory for the file name (i.e., `.gitignore`) very much like git.  In other words, you don't need a single file for the entire workspace. Try it...  I was pleasantly surprised!  (Note though that Perforce's parsing/processing is not the same as git's so the behavior isn't identical, especially with respect to wildcards and subdirectories.)

Comment: @ChuckBatson Huh, I stand corrected, thanks! I still think its reliance on an environment variable is asking for problems, but being to specify multiple ignore lists is nice.

Comment: Does this have to only be configured on the P4D server? I have set this up on my AWS instance but it doesn't seem to work when testing via P4V on the client and local workspace machine.

Comment: NOTE:  `P4IGNORE=~/.p4ignore` doesn't work because Perforce is too stupid to resolve the `~`.  Use P4IGNORE=`/home/yourusername/.p4ignore` instead.

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to do it directly in Perforce:

- Connection menu
- Edit Current Workspace...

Navigate the project tree.
Right-click on the file or folder.
Choose to include or exclude the file, the folder, the entire tree.

Comment: This only works if your workspace is compatible with the tree view. The one in question wasn't.

Answer (score 3):

This works great for me:

```
//depot/... //my_workspace_name/...
-//depot/.../.git/... //my_workspace_name/.../.git/...
-//depot/.../xcuserdata/... //my_workspace_name/.../xcuserdata/...
-//depot/.../xcschemes/... //my_workspace_name/.../xcschemes/...
-//depot/.../xcdebugger/... //my_workspace_name/.../xcdebugger/...
```

Comment: Note that I'm mapping the entire depot. (Although I only sync what I need.) Tested using P4V 2011.1 on OS X 10.7.4

Answer (score 1):

This may not be relevant, but if there are spaces in any of your paths you need to ensure you have correctly enclosed them in "" but dont enclose the - inside the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

When I added the folders to ignore, they were not applied because I specified the path to the folders, and it was a mistake, you just need to specify the name of the folder that you want to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Method won't work with local depot, but if you have a stream depot, you can create a virtual stream and exclude your binaries folders in centralized way for all developers.

Advanced path settings of virtual stream could be something like that:

```
share ...
exclude bin/...
exclude logs/...
```

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4v/Content/P4V/streams.virtual.html

Answer (score -1):

I would go ahead with the Reconcile Offline Work and do everything but the submit.  Before the submit, do the following:

p4 revert //Client/Foo/.../*.user

p4 revert //Client/Foo/.../bin/...

p4 revert //Client/Foo/.../obj/...

It's not automated, but that's the best I can think of at the moment.

Comment: That's why I would like to use ignore, but yes, I'm manually reverting stuff (or may end up writing a shellscript for that), and this is a joke.

Comment: @SzabolcsKurdi, Perforce now has a way to ignore directories and files, both via the P4IGNORE variable, and through the Ignored field in the stream specification.  Don't have time to do an actual answer right now.

Comment: I tried to use P4Ignore but it didn't work in the gui at all (and I find it quite cumbersome, compared to gitignore for example); maybe it's me, but I couldn't find a proper solution. I'd be glad if you could tell me how you did it.

Comment: @SzabolcsKurdi, are you using streams?

Comment: I use command line + p4v + vs plugin; hopefully I cleared it up with support though, ignore only kicks in during the add process. If I can't find a solution I'll open a question instead of spamming the comment thread.