# Perforce p4ignore with P4v

Tags: perforce, p4v

Does anyone know how to ignore files and/or directories with P4V? I added p4ignore by p4 command line, but P4V does not pickup that.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is your P4V up to date? P4V has supported P4IGNORE for years: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3099534/193453

Comment: Thank you Bryan for your comment. I use p4 to add ignore path but P4v still shows the file in p4ignore. Do you know how can I do this on P4v using GUI?

Answer (score 0):

P4V does work with p4ignore...to a point.

In your workspace view, you will still see the local files that would be "ignored" by the ignore file. The reasoning behind this is multifold, but the main reason is that to show a local view, P4V stats the local directories, and there's no good way other than to constantly check with p4ignore files (and that involves walking the directory tree on up to the workspace root) every time it looks at the tree. Ends up being terribly inefficient.

However, P4V still respects the p4ignore file, and if you attempt to add any file that would be ignored, it properly gives you an error message (with the ability to silently ignore the files as well if you want).

Comment: Thank you for your response. It would make sense to show the file in workspace, however, my problem is that I want to get diff between my project (angular 2) and repository. Since node_module is not require to be added to repository, event when I have p4ignore, diff still show all files in this folder as difference between repository and local. I could handle that by filter, however, since number of files are more than 100k's it takes very long time (couple of minutes) to show diff. I am looking for a solution to add p4ignore which make p4v to ignore node_module folder when finding diff.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yeah, I'd reach out to support and ask about Folder Diff filtering enhancement. This was something that I know came up while I was there.