# Is there a way to get "p4v reconcile offline work"?

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to get `"p4v reconcile offline work"` to behave the same way as the command-line `"p4 reconcile"` when it comes to `p4ignore`?

I've read [Can you "ignore" a directory in P4V?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099505/can-you-ignore-a-directory-in-p4v) and https://community.perforce.com/s/article/1282 however the problem with those is they are not very flexible. We want different p4ignore files per project so having to either set absolute paths, change the p4v start-in directory, or set a fixed env variable ruin the flexibility.

Ideally, it would work identical to the command line where we create a p4config file in the root of a project and then point its p4ignore variable to a side-by-side p4ignore file which contains the ignore specifications.

Example:

p4config.txt

```
P4IGNORE=p4ignore.txt
```

p4ignore.txt

```
*.obj
```

If I run `"p4 reconcile"` from the command-line in the root folder of that project it will correctly reconcile everything but obj files.

If I run `"p4v reconcile offline work"` from the root folder of that project it will reconcile everything *including* the obj files which should have been ignored.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since P4V isn't open-source it's not possible to fix bugs in it yourself.

The answer to "how do I get P4V to do this thing the command line does" is generally "write a custom tool and use that instead of the built-in P4V command".

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was a configuration error on my part, but if its a bug then I'm out of luck. Back to the command line I go!