# How can I tell P4SCC to ignore files?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, perforce

I started on a new project a few months ago and am forced to use perforce (pun intended). I have experience with a variety of distributed and monolithic VCS, especially SVN with Ankh as SC plugin in visual studio...that said, I have been evading some..quirks perforce has by applying various workarounds you can find, mainly here on SO. This issue though is something I do not want to give up on so fast, so I hope some of you guys can help me out with it.

I installed the P4SCC plugin in my VS 2010, and at least I got to open the solution and it seems to work as expected. But since VS creates a bunch of metafiles, namely *.vspscc and other *scc* files, the plugin lists thos in the "pending checkins" window. In P4V you can just revert files marked for add and they will be ignored, even though they remain in the file system...not so here. Apparently P4 does not consider the files as "added" or "changed", so will not revert. Since the files are not part of the solution or projects (at least according to VS), they do not show up in the solution explorer and therefor I cannot use the "File->Source Control->Remove file from source control" option.

I tried different things to ignore those files, since I do not want to check them into the repository. Sadly, I only find ways to get files out of the view in P4V as described here:
[Can you "ignore" a file in Perforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449/can-you-ignore-a-file-in-perforce) Since I told P4SCC to use the same workspace as I do in P4V, I expected those changes to apply to it as well...but once again perforce has NOT behaved as I would have expected.

The temptation is getting bigger to just check in the darn things (alghough there's easily 100+ of them...), but that just seems wrong. So my question is:

**Is there any way, no matter how hacky, to get P4SCC to ignore these files, or any files in that manner?**

Comment: As I don't use P4SCC myself, all I can suggest is to contact Perforce support. I've made some really good experiences with that.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I intend to do so tomorrow, but my experience with tech support is usually much worse than the quality of most answers here on SO.

Comment: Concerning your problems with p4v, is it that you don't want to see the files in p4v, or you are trying to "revert" them from p4v?  If it is the former, click on the filter/funnel icon by your Depot/Workspace tab and choose to "Hide Files not in Depot."

Comment: I do not have problems with P4V (in this case). I cannot revert them in P4V, since it does not consider them "added". P4SCC on the other hand claims the files ARE "added", but does not let me revert them (since perforce then again thinks they are not...), and I cannot even check them in...since perforce knows they were not marked for add...

Comment: @galaktor: If you have had problems with tech support, you can't possibly have been in contact with _Perforce_ support. They're nothing short of brilliant to talk to.

Comment: No, I was not referring to Perforce support, I am fairly new to Perforce and had not resorted to that yet. I DID ask them later, though, and it turns out that there is now way to tell P4SCC to ignore files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Perforce support I had to learn that there apparently is not way to tell P4SCC to ignore files.

> For later releases, including Visual Studio 2010 which uses .NET Framework Version 4.0, the P4SCC plugin will automatically add all appropriate files when VS projects are added to source control.  So, in general, do not change the contents of the changelist.  **There is no option to exclude such files in the P4SCC plugin.**