# .gitignore alternative in Perforce

Tags: git, github, resharper, perforce, gitignore

We've been using github enterprise account to host a number of projects in the cloud. Now we are moving to perforce on-premises installation.

We are mostly developing in ASP.NET MVC + using ReSharper. With git we had a .gitignore file in the project folder that allowed us to automatically filter out folders and file types on commit, so we don't flood the repository with personal project files.

How do I configure Perforce so that it automatically filters _Resharper* folder during the commit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you "ignore" a file in Perforce?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449/can-you-ignore-a-file-in-perforce)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starting [2012.1 you do have a `p4ignore`](http://www.perforce.com/blog/120214/new-20121-p4ignore) which avoids adding files to the depot.

You have other alternatives explained in "[Can you “ignore” a file in Perforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449/can-you-ignore-a-file-in-perforce)"