# How to remove existing files from Perforce and ignore them (without deleting them)

Tags: python, perforce

I've started working on a Python project using Perforce for VCS that previously only had a single developer.

Currently all the pyc files are in source control which is making merges a pain.

I've seen I can add P4ignore files to keep pyc files out of VCS as carry on working but I need a way to remove them from perforce without removing them from disk.

Or (and this has only occurred to me as I ask the question), as a new-to-python person, can I just delete all the pyc files from VCS (and so from disk) and then let my p4ignore file stop newly created pyc files from getting back into VCS?

Comment: As stated in [this other SO post][1], you can use the P4IGNORE variable.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449/can-you-ignore-a-file-in-perforce

Comment: Ah ha, I'd seen that post and mention P4Ignore in my question. AS I'm new to Python I wasn't completely certain that it was safe to simply delete the PYC files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely delete the `.pyc` files and then ignore them from here on.  Python will automatically generate new `.pyc` files when the modules are imported/updated.

Generating the `.pyc` files is quite fast too, so there's no real noticeable performance difference even when python generates new files.