# In perforce how can I delete files from a directory in my workspace where the files are not part of the workspace?

Tags: perforce

In perforce how can I delete files from a directory in my workspace where the files I want deleted are not part of the workspace?

I have a directory on my file system with files it gets from perforce but after some processes run, it creates some new files in those directories.

Is there a perforce command to remove these generated files that are not part of my workspace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perforce 2013.2 has a `p4 status` command, which is an alias for `p4 reconcile -n`

I don't know if it was available in earlier versions.

Answer (score 3):

This is my quick implementation of `p4 nothave`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# List files present, but not in perforce.

tmpd="$(mktemp -d /tmp/nothave.XXXXXXXX)"
trap "rm -rf $tmpd" EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM

p4 have | awk -F' - ' '{print $2}' | sort >$tmpd/have.txt

root=$(p4 info | awk -F': ' '$1=="Client root"{print $2}')
find $root -type f | sort >$tmpd/find.txt

comm -13 $tmpd/have.txt $tmpd/find.txt
```

This will produce a list of files, which can then be piped into `xargs rm` in order to be deleted.  Be careful to inspect the list before deleting though.  You may well find things you didn't expect in there.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the "Reconcile Offline Work" option in p4v and p4 to accomplish this without any scripting.  In p4v, right click any directory in Depot view and select "Reconcile Offline Work".

The middle pane will have "Local files not in depot".  You can select any or all of these, right click and choose "Delete Local file".

Easy!

Comment: This works nicely - thanks!  I notice that this method leaves all the resulting empty directories, if any, on the local system.

Comment: On a Unix based system `find /dir -empty -type d -delete` can solve that one easily.

Answer (score 2):

If using Linux/Unix, in the Bourne shell family, you can type

```
find . -type f | p4 -x- files 2>&1| grep "no such file" | cut -f1 -d" " | xargs rm
```

Similarly, for symbolic links, type

```
find . -type l | p4 -x- files 2>&1| grep "no such file" | cut -f1 -d" " | xargs rm
```

Above is letter 'el', not 'one'.

Whether there is an equivalent in Windows I do not know.

Comment: This answer did not work for me on linux. The "p4 files ..." does not list any files that are not part of the workspace. I think the original question was misinterpreted. Try it: "mkdir tmp; cd tmp; touch not_in_workspace; p4 files ..."

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify/delete files that are not part of your workspace from within perforce. You will have to write external scripts for that.

Comment: I think he used the term 'workspace' in two different ways.  The files he's trying to delete are within his workspace, but not checked in (as is evidenced by the fact that perforce is putting other files alongside the files in question).

Answer (score 1):

This is a little awkward in powershell, because p4 sends the can't-find-file message to the error stream rather than std out.

```
ps > $error.clear()
ps > dir | %{p4 fstat -T "haveRev" $_} 2>$null
ps > $error | %{$_.Exception.ToString().Split()[1]} | %{del $_}
```

The second line should produces errors such as `"FILENAME.EXT - no such file(s)."` It can be a bit flaky if you have anything other than these exceptions in the error stream, so beware.

Comment: ...still learning powershell, so if there's a quicker way to do this, let me know.

Comment: You can redirect stderr in PowerShell, and it will nicely wrap the errors in ErrorRecords (add "-r" to dir to search the whole tree):  dir | % {p4.exe fstat $_.FullName 2>&1} | ? {$_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]} | %{$_.Exception.ToString().Split()[1]} | % {del $_}

Answer (score -4):

You can use `p4 nothave` to determine the files that are not managed by perforce. Depending on the output of `p4 nothave` you might be able to do `p4 nothave  | xargs rm`, but be sure to check the result of `p4 nothave` before running that (so that you don't delete something important by accident).

Comment: Weird, my p4 exe does not have a nothave. Is this in linux versions only maybe?

Comment: p4 nothave doesn't exist.  You have to fake it with find, "p4 have" and comm(1).

Comment: How can this be accepted answer, I am going to downvote hoping op will return to correct.

Comment: It turns out that this is a non-standard extension in a particular implementation used by my employer. Deleting answer.

Comment: Apparently, I cannot delete this since this has been accepted as an answer. @Matt, can you unmark / select a different answer, so that I can delete this?