# How to add files to default changelist in Perforce .NET API?

Tags: .net, perforce, p4.net

We have a system that generates reports and will dump them in a P4 workspace folder. I am building a .NET program to run on a schedule that will submit these reports to P4.

How do I find the unversioned files, add them to a changelist then submit them?

Comment: @ChrisF I am trying to use fstat to get info about files that are unversioned but I can't see an argument that would suit the purpose.

Comment: You could just try to add them and let Perforce figure this out for you. It won't add files already in the depot. (Is that your only issue, or are you trying to deal with updated, and possibly deleted, files as well?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to do using the P4V client as Reconcile Offline Work automatically adds untracked files and opens for edit any with changes.

As for doing it procedurally through an API, you might be out of luck for similar functionality but have a look at [a powershell solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3219246/105377)