# How to show new files in Perforce workspace?

Tags: perforce

When I add new files to my project which is managed by Perforce, how can I get a list of the new files I've added (the ones Perforce does not know about yet) so I can make sure I don't miss any in my changeset?

Something like 'svn status | grep ^\?' or 'git status' to show the unstaged, unknown files.

Thanks!
-Casey

Answer (score 3):

Find the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272/finding-untracked-files-in-a-perforce-tree) on SO and check the other answers and comments too. There is no direct command available from command-line. But you can use a powershell script or a GUI for it.

Comment: Guess I should have searched for 'untracked'... Well, at least this might improve the odds of the next poor developer finding it :)

Comment: Did that helped you? If you think this is the right answer, accept it so that the next person searching will know that it is what he needs to look. The green Checkmark next to answer is the one to accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is provided in the similar question linked to by Teja.  However, if you want an easy command line solution that deals specifically with added files, you can do the following

```
find directory -type f | p4 -x- add
```

for normal files, and

```
find directory -type l | p4 -x- add
```

for links.  (Letter 'el', not 'one' in above command)

Perforce simply refuses to add any files that are already in version control.  The only problem is that this adds everything, including binary files.

Answer (score 1):

For P4V, right-click on a folder in the workspace tree and click "Find File...". In "All or part of a file name", type "*.cs". Then sort by filetype - new files will have filetype "none".

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to apply multiple filters, e.g., "*.cs; *.aspx". So you have to filter one filetype at a time. Also, you have to be patient if there are thousands of files - the sorting mechanism won't work properly until the asynchronous find process has completed.

(The "Reconcile Offline Work..." option isn't working for me. I'm using P4V June 2009.)

Comment: I'm sure that this guy was *not* looking for a GUI solution. Sorry, no vote :)

Comment: @sorin Maybe asker didn't think of using GUI but would have been fine with it. Anyway, useful for other guys (like me) +1

Answer (score 1):

You might take advantage of the p4 files command

find . -type f | xargs p4 files 2>&1 | grep 'no such file(s)'

You could even filter on file type like this.

find . -type f | xargs p4 files 2>&1 | grep 'no such file(s)' | grep 'cpp'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a unix one liner using find and p4, fstat and awk that saved my bacon.

[How to find untracked files in a Perforce tree? (analogue of svn status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272/finding-untracked-files-in-a-perforce-tree/100126#100126)

Answer (score 0):

The perforce "reconcile" command with the "add files" and "preview" options will show new, un-added files, without adding them:

> p4 rec -an