# What is the p4 command equivalent to something like svn status

Tags: perforce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find untracked files in a Perforce tree? (analogue of svn status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272/how-to-find-untracked-files-in-a-perforce-tree-analogue-of-svn-status)

I want to know what p4 command that will show me which files have changed, which files are not checked in, etc.

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate of [How to find untracked files in a Perforce tree? (analogue of svn status)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272/how-to-find-untracked-files-in-a-perforce-tree-analogue-of-svn-status).   That question was about one specific use of a command like svn/hg/bzr/git status, finding untracked files, whereas this question is about a single command that can summarize the workspace status, both offline changes and changes already in an uncommitted changeset.     Moreover, thew answer in the linked-to-page is not completely correct.

Comment: Since this question was incorrectly closed, I have asked a new question [(What is the p4 command equivalent to something like git/hg/bzr/svn status? (Hint: not `p4 status`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937962/what-is-the-p4-command-equivalent-to-something-like-git-hg-bzr-svn-status-hint), and answered it myself. (Although I welcome a better answer - which is why I ran into this incorrect answer in the first place.)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using perforce properly, "p4 opened" is what you're looking for.  It will tell you what files you have opened for change.  If you want to be able to change files locally, THEN open them for edit (or delete, etc.,) then you're walking out of the usage patterns that perforce expects users to abide by and you're treading on dangerous ground.

Perforce does provide mechanisms that will allow you to detect these things - if you're going to insist on working this way.  "p4 fstat" will allow you to get the expected md5sum for a file from the server.  Comparing that with the local md5sum will tell you if the file has changed.  You could, alternatively, compare file dates - if the modification date on your local machine does not match that given by fstat, you can be fairly certain that it has changed, but to be certain, you'd have to do the md5sum check.

Comment: The trouble with 'p4 opened', 'p4 fstat', and 'p4 diff' is that they only tell you about the files Perforce knows about. They don't compare your local workspace to what's in the depot, and they can't detect new files, so you're never really getting the true status of your workspace files. Whereas the new 'p4 status' command does all that and really does tell you what you need to do to reconcile your worksapce. There's some info about it [in the afore-mentioned blog post](http://www.perforce.com/blog/120126/new-20121-p4reconcile-p4status).

Comment: "p4 opened" worked to let me know what files I changed. I knew I hadn't added any files, so it was enough for my purposes. thanks

Answer (score 4):

In the upcoming 2012.1 release there a new command named `p4 status` that will do the equivalent to that as if you were using SVN.

```
p4 status 
src/tools/this.rb - reconcile to edit //depot/stuff/src/tools/this.rb#3 
src/tools/that.rb - reconcile to add //depot/stuff/src/tools/that.rb#1 
src/tools/other.rb - reconcile to delete //depot/stuff/src/tools/other.rb#2
```

For more information, read the announcement on the [Perforce Blog](http://www.perforce.com/blog/120126/new-20121-p4reconcile-p4status).

Answer (score 1):

While awaiting the official 2012.1 release you have basically two options:

- Do it yourself using the command line
- Use P4Vs "Reconcile Offline Work"

More details can be found in the [Perforce KB](http://kb.perforce.com/article/2).